# Excel values not updating unless text re-written

Tags: excel, text, countif

i am having some problem with a simple countif, it doesn't seem to like my text data even though it is duplicated from other tables.

The original:
[image]

If i rewrite the text it updates the cell with the correct values?
[image]

Any way i can fix this without rewriting all those cells? i have auto calculate on and have re calculated the sheet but to no avail, copy and paste doesn't seem to update either which makes it a long manual process?

Comment: You probably have non printable characters like spaces on the front or end.  Which is making it not find a match.

Comment: Hi Scott, the values are directly copied from another table where the formula works, i am simply counting separate data using the same parameter and formula structure